# How can get result when call a function by send transaction way?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

I learned interacting with smart contract and call a function.
I am using UniswapV2 Router's function for quickswap.

```
function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint[] memory amounts)
```

And my code

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)
const data =  contract.methods.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOutMin, pair, account, deadline).encodeABI()
// Transfer some tokens
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account, (err, txCount) => {

  const txObject = {
    nonce:    web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    to: contractAddress,
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(800000), // Raise the gas limit to a much higher amount
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
    data: data 
  }   

  const tx = new Tx(txObject, {'chain':'ropsten'})
  tx.sign(privateKey1)

  const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
  const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
    console.log('err:', err, 'txHash:', txHash)
```

How can I get `(uint[] memory amounts)` by this way?